# What is the preferable location for putting java libraries in play framework project?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have a source code of some java library, so what is the preferable way of using it? Where should I put it? Should I `jar` it? Or compile it? Or go ahead and use it as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on many factors, are there more than one people working on the project, will there be for long, do you have access to a corporate maven or ivy repo, to mention a few.

If it is only relevant to that webapp, put it in the project, if you use it in other projects make it a separate project, if it is a codebase that will never change, make it a separate library and make a release out of it so that you don't have to compile it and run its tests on every build.

The list goes on and on, but I hope it helped a little bit at least.